# Keep somebody from doing something by accident

Tags: c++

I encountered a problem basically can be explain by the code below:

```
void (*fn_ptr)();

template<typename T> void Second(){
    //do something
}

template<typename T> void First() {
    //do init
    fn_ptr = Second<T>;
}
```

The function `First` and function `Second` both need to be `template function` and will only be called through function pointer `fn_ptr`. Function `First` must be called once before function `Second` is called. You don't need manually call function Second. So the only thing we should do before `fun_ptr` is used somewhere is this:

```
fn_ptr = First<SomeType>;
```

**There comes the question**: How can I keep people from doing this:

```
fn_ptr = Second<SomeType>;
```

ps: I know how to do it when function `First` and function `Second` are not `template function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it work. Just make the two functions to be static member functions of a class template:

```
template<typename T> class Foo{
public:
void First() {
    //do init
    fn_ptr = Second<T>;
}

private:
void Second(){
    //do something
}
};
```

and then:

```
fn_ptr = Foo<SomeType>::First; // OK
fn_ptr = Foo<SomeType>::Second; // Error: Second is inaccessable
```

All I want to say is holly shit. `fn_ptr` works well after function `First` assign a private static member function to it. Well, it works on VC++ 2012. I don't know if it comply with the iso standard or not but I guess it's portable.

Comment: Of course it is portable, and you shouldn't be surprised: The static class method `First` specifically grants access to the private method. There's no violation of encapsulation, since it must know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Without going in the details of it, I would use classes and the fn_ptr = ... would become a function. Then in the function you can test if fn_ptr is still NULL, then the rhs must be dynamic castable to the first class.

I'm not too sure you could do much to prevent the error otherwise.